# Does OpenJpa return resultlist in any particular order

Tags: openjpa

does openjpa return resultlist in a particular order even if Order by clause is not mentioned in query??
i m getting the result in ascending order and have not written order by clause.

Comment: No it does not insert any OrderBy clause behind the scene. What you get is a row ordering provided by database engine, it could be random or primary key ordering but you cannot exactly count on it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<property name="openjpa.Log" value="SQL=trace"/>
```

You could always enable trace to see what SQL is being generated.